# Assumptions with piecewise problem?

Tags: functions, matrix, assumptions, piecewise

I am trying to apply the assumpion of 0<s<1 throughout the calculation however the  piecewise condition does not accept it automatically. Is there any way to avoid the manual choice of x>0.

The mathematica code:

```
T = Refine[{{s, 0}, {0, 1 - s}}, s \[Element] Reals && 0 < s < 1]
{vals, vecs} = Refine[Eigensystem[rho1]];
M = Refine[Transpose[vecs]];
Inverse[M];
DG = Refine[DiagonalMatrix[vals]];
F[x_] := Piecewise[{{x*Log[x], x > 0}, {0, x == 0}}, null];
FD = Refine[MatrixFunction[F, DG]];
-Tr[M.FD.Inverse[M]]]
```

The output:

[image]

Since I claim at the start that 0<s<1 I want mathematica to automatically choose the 1-s>0 that I am interested in and not the whole function. I tried Refine but still doesn't work

Any help?

Comment: Assumptions inside Refine are only active there. If you want global assumptions, you need to set the variable $Assumptions

Comment: I have done that already..still not working with in the peacewise function..thanks though

Comment: Note that you still need to use Simplify. $Assumptions will not be applied automatically.

Comment: My god, that was it. Real thanks man